# Unable to Use RequestStacks for Adding Content to Line-Item Payload after Shopware 6.5.4.0

Tags: symfony, twig, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

How do I add content into a line item after Shopware 6.5.4.0 without RequestStacks?

Since the update to Shopware 6.5.4.0, it seems that using RequestStacks to add content to the payload of a line item doesn't work anymore.

Previously, I utilized the following code snippet:

```
<label class="form-label" for="product-instruction-{{ product.id }}"></label>
 <input type="text"
        placeholder="Additional instruction"
        id="product-instruction-{{ product.id }}"
        name="lineItems[{{ product.id }}][payload][instruction]"
        class="form-control"
                            />
```

However, after 6.5.4.0, the line:
`name="lineItems[{{ product.id }}][payload][instruction]"`

is giving the Error:

`mb_strlen(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataBag\RequestDataBag given`

Is there an alternative method or workaround to achieve the same outcome?